# Will search engines reindex a page that has been set to redirect on to a newer site page?

Tags: redirects, search-engine-indexing, 301-redirect, iis

We were asked by a client to change a website so that any pages/Urls we were hosting on an older site would now redirect to a newer site hosted somewhere else and a different domain name to boot.

We did this by changing each page in the IIS site management, to redirect to a url on their new domain instead of rendering a page locally.

According to the redirect tool here: http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php . What we have done is search engine friendly.

Problem now is... the client has been on a course learning all about meta tags and so thinks they have a better understanding of the "matrix" (remember there is no spoon). As Google still has the older site appearing in a search, this isnt helping matters.

I have tried to explain, we have to wait for Google to reindex. I'm not blowing smoke am I?

I'm now starting to wonder... will the older site always appear in a search, even though the pages don't exist?  Is there a better way I should be redirecting their site to ensure google will stop keeping an index of pages that no longer exist and would instead replace them with the content in the newer site?

a suggestion on the site mentioned above is to use the code:

```
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.new-url.com/"
```

Does using the option in the IIS management tool to redirect the url not do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a while for Google and the other search engines to notice pages have moved and adjust their indexes accordingly. It definitely does not happen quickly much less overnight. So even though you have set up redirects those old pages will still show in the SERPs for a little while. Fortunately when a user clicks on the search results they will be taken to the new page thanks to the redirect. Basically at this point it is a waiting game.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your question, but I am guessing your answer will be here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734